# Not able to search on enter key in tagsInput autocomplete Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have integrated tagsInput for the autocomplete in angular js.

i have included file ng-tags-input.min and added below code in my view.

```
<tags-input ng-model="searchTerm"
                display-property="Name" 
                add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
                replace-spaces-with-dashes='false'
            placeholder="Search option"
              >
        <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" min-length='3'></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
```

also added code in controller for get data for auto complete

```
$scope.loadTags = function (query) {
                        if (query != undefined) {
                            var info = data;
                            var items = ($filter('filter')(info, {Name: query}));
                            return items;
                        } else {
                            return data;
                        }

                    }
```

Every going fine. i am getting all data in auto complete but the problem after selecting option i am not able to search on enter key press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please explain your problem again?.
Whether do you have a problem to select the searched result by ENTER key press or auto complete serach is not working?

Here i am giving the sample code that we used.

```
<tags-input class="`tagsInput`" ng-model="ctrl.nameList" 
                                    display-property="fullName"
                                    key-property="name"
                                    min-length="1"
                                    max-tags="{{ctrl.Count}"
                                    min-tags="0"
                                    add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
                                    replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
                                    placeholder="Add"
                                    enforce-max-tags>
                            <auto-complete source="ctrl.loadTags($query)"
                                           min-length="3"
                                           max-results-to-show={{ctrl.seletedListCount}}">
                            </auto-complete>
                        </tags-input>
```

and in your loadTags function

```
self.loadTags = function (query) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            someService.loadUsers(query).then(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    self.seletedListCount = data ? data.length : 1000;
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }
                else {
                    deferred.reject();
                }
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Inside the loadTags, you can call the service and you can show the searched results. No need to search again by selecting the auto complete result and press enter

Comment: i am able to select by auto suggestion but after selecting auto suggestion we have one value on which we can search so once i press enter then it should work search contain.. for more information you can see in stackoverflow when we create quetion in tag you can get auto suggestion on enter you can select from option once you selected then press enter it allow to search..

Comment: i have updated my answer. Is it possible to use the service call inside the loadTag function to show the search results in the auto complete

Comment: @cirl thanks for help but its not working for me. have you any other option?

Comment: could you please try by onTagAdded event? [refer](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api)

Comment: on enter key it should submit my data

Comment: Thanks ciril it helps me a lot
and  i have another issue it is resolved by putting ng-submit in outer wrapper of form